# How do I make my TCP server run forever?

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I have this code I got from the docs:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket

TCP_IP = '192.168.1.66'
TCP_PORT = 40000
BUFFER_SIZE = 20  # Normally 1024, but we want fast response

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.listen(1)

conn, addr = s.accept()

print 'Connection address:', addr

while True:
    data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    if not data: break
    print "received data:", data
    conn.send(data)

conn.close()
```

But it closes down each time I disconnect, how to I make it run for ever?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to call `accept()` once for each connection you wish to handle.  to a first approximation:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.listen(1)

while True:    
    conn, addr = s.accept()

    print 'Connection address:', addr

    while True:
        data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
        if not data: break
        print "received data:", data
        conn.send(data)

    conn.close()
```

Answer (score 6):

Try and change the line

```
if not data: break
```

to

```
if not data: continue
```

this way instead of exiting the loop, it will wait for more data